# c++ concurrent getline on ifstream

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, mutex, getline

I want to perform a join on three files and as a last step, I have to compute a sum from a certain column of the joined file.
Let's say this is the part of the code where I read the last file line by line and, based on some criterion that depends on the other two files, I add the value in the 4th field of the line to my sum (see the if statement at the end).

```
   std::ifstream l_file(this->lineitem);
   std::string l_line;

   // read lineitem file, get orderkey (and most importantly, get l_quantity and not l_extendedprice..), sum up quantities
   while (std::getline(l_file, l_line, '\n'))
   {
      std::istringstream iss(l_line);
      std::string l_orderkey, l_quantity;

      std::getline(iss, l_orderkey, '|');
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
      {
         std::getline(iss, l_quantity, '|');
      }
      std::getline(iss, l_quantity, '|');

      if (customerMap.find(orderMap[std::stoi(l_orderkey)]) != customerMap.end()) {
         sum += std::stoi(l_quantity);
         n += 1;
      }

   }
```

I tried to parallelize this part by splitting the lines of the files among a number of threads, but apparently, this does not work because there is a race condition on the getline call, causing the threads to interfere in their individual getline calls (at some point, std::stoi(l_orderkey) throws an exception, because l_orderkey contains the wrong part of the line, for example a string of non-numeric chars that is also contained in some field in the line, and obviously, this can't be transformed into an integer).

I then used a mutex to lock the first call of getline, such that every thread can read the line into its local l_line variable without being disturbed by another thread. However, even this did not work. I declared the mutex as a class variable.

Is there a possibility to parallelize the code anyways?
I can provide the whole code if the above snippet is not sufficient.
Thank you lots guys!

Comment: All file-handling are in essence serial anyway, so there's no real benefit from doing it in threads in your program. Read the file into memory, and if you need to do any parallel processing on the data do it once the file is loaded.

Comment: Don't just don't parallelize reading/writing ONE file.  What performance issue are you trying to solve? What you can do is to load all data into memory and then you can parallelize operations on the data in memory. Probably you need to load all 3 input files into memory already anyway so use that.

Comment: If not even a mutex helps to get at least correct (not necessarily performant) behaviour, you're doing something wrong. If you provided a [mcve], people could perhaps help you fix that code. As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: If you don't want to read the whole file at once, you can use a producer-consumer setup with one thread reading the lines into a queue and a couple of threads processing the queue in parallel. But that only makes sense if the cost of processing a line greatly outweighs the cost of allocating the string and finding the line ends. It may also need tuning, e.g. producing larger string batches (let's say 64 kiB worth of raw data) to cut down on synchronization cost

Comment: Thank you everyone! Also @UlrichEckhardt thank you for referring me to the two resources. I will prepare a min reproducible example if I run into further issues.

About the speed up issue: My program involves three while loops that look pretty much like the one I posted. From what you said, it does not seem like I could generate a significant speed up from parallelizing the loops themselves if this would technically lead to sequential processing - I will still try the version with the local copies, but I have large files so I believe this will slow things down.